# Return before call another function

Tags: php, multithreading, function

Here if my function

```
function abc{

echo 'abc';
another_function();
return true;

}
```

i want it to return true and make independent to another_function() call output. dont want to wait for executing another_function()

is it possible ? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think, you are looking for async php libs.
For example [amphp](https://github.com/amphp), [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org) or [Swoole](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src)

Or you can google for "coroutines in php"